# Load scripts along with content in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am loading a set of images from another page using jquery `load()` function.  I want the images that are loaded to be able to trigger the colorbox script but it is not working.  I have all of the scripts on the page that triggers the load, but the script does not get applied to the fresh ajax content.  How could I make this work?

### Update

Thanks for the responses!  It now works using the on function.. so I have something like this :

```
<a href="http://something.com" class="cbox"><img ... /></a>

        $j(".cbox").on( "click", function(){
              $j.fn.colorbox({ iframe:true,  scrolling: false, innerWidth: '650px', innerHeight: '390px' }); 
              return false;
              });
```

It seems to sort of work.. however now colorbox cant grab the href, it is returning that as undefined...  but I guess that is another matter.

Comment: Some code would help a lot...

Comment: If the string contain both scripts and image I doubt scripts could be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's new `.on()` method, which replaces `.live()` and `.delegate()`. It works on elements that were added to the DOM after the code ran.

Had you posted some code, I'd have some to post back, but basically it looks like

```
$('imgselect').on('event',function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

`event` can be `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `click`, etc.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to do the trick.  Sort-of... I am accepting your answer but if you could take a look at my new problem and offer any advice that would be great :)

Comment: @Zac, Are the images also hyperlinks? Can we see more code please? Actually, it would be best just to link us to the page.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for all your help.  It is just in a staging environment right now.  Its ok, i think i can figure this out, you gave me what I needed with `on`.. but now the colorbox script wont grab the correct href and just returns undefined.  Yes the images are hyperlinks.

Comment: I updated my question with some code to hopefully make it a little clearer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Zac, I still need more code to see what's wrong. I don't know what you're trying do with the href or how you're trying to access it, etc. As much code as possible please.

Comment: I figured it out, I just needed to define the `href` in the colorbox arguments with `this.href`

Answer (score 1):

Try using requireJS.

This works as a script loader, and a library module controller for defining use for script methods.

http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html
-----EDIT-------

Okay I only half read your question. Try using .delegate() instead of binding to just an element, because when a fresh element is loaded in via Javascript whether in a string, DOM addition, or AJAX call, that selector that executed initially doesn't see the new element.

However .delegate() can work while watching a certain DOM element for change, and if it may be global I'd do something like this:

```
$('body').delegate("a[rel='theTriggerElement']", "click", function () { //Do Trigger Event});
```

This will watch the body element for any new `"a[rel='theTriggerElement']"` elements, and apply the event to them. Remember not to use `.live()` as it's deprecated.